# Notation in the proof of the existence of Chern connection (Huybrechts's book)

Tags: complex-geometry

My question is simple. I had read about the existence of Chern connection in the Huybrechts book Complex Geometry p. 177 but I don't remember meaning of some notation :

[image]

Here the $A$ is the connection matrix with respect to the $\{e_i\}$

Q. What is the $\partial $? I know the $\bar{\partial}$ as follows (his book p.109):

[image]

; i.e., $\bar{\partial}_E : \mathcal{A}^{0}(E) = \mathcal{A}^{0,0}(E) \to \mathcal{A}^{0,1}(E)$

But what $\partial$ does mean? defined similarly as in the proof of the Lemma 2.6.23 (in the above image)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that $H$ is a matrix of smooth complex-valued functions on $X$. The expression $\partial H$ is notation for the matrix of $(1,0)$-forms $[\partial h_{ij}]$, i.e. $\partial$ acts on the matrix $H$ by acting on each entry.

The Dolbeault operator $\bar{\partial}_E$ is defined for any holomorphic vector bundle (this is Lemma $2.6.23$). As you can see from the proof, the construction relies on the transition functions of $E$ being holomorphic, i.e. in the kernel of $\bar{\partial}$. For an analogous global operator $\partial_E$ to exist, one would need the transition functions to be in the kernel of $\partial$ which, for a holomorphic trivialisation, would imply they are locally constant.

Comment: Yes. $\partial H$ maybe means that $[\partial_X h_{ij}] $, where 
  
   $ \partial_X := \prod ^{1,0}_{X} \circ d_X : \mathcal{A}^{0,0}_X(X) \to \mathcal{A}^{1,0}_{X}(X) $ as in the definition 2.6.9 in his book p.106
   
   Now I'am considering when $\partial_E$ (if defined) is same as $\partial$
   
   Anyway, thank you for answer!

Comment: If $\partial_E$ is defined, it acts on sections of $E$ (and can be extended to act on $(p,q)$-forms with values in $E$), while $\partial$ acts on $(p, q)$-forms.

Comment: Yes. Thank you. I will check it!. Uhm, if we let $E$ be the trivial bundle, then perhaps $\partial_E$ is same as $\partial$ ?

Comment: If $E$ is the trivial line bundle, then they do indeed coincide.

Comment: Yes. O.K. ~ I see.